# Rails 3 full-text search options (gems, plugins, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if there were any suggestions for how to best roll with full text searching in your Rails 3 apps? Thinking Sphinx and acts_as_ferret aren't updated for Rails 3 yet, and even basic activerecord search helpers like Searchlogic also aren't there yet.

Any thoughts? Are you using any forked versions of the above gems that have been updated to Rails 3?

Comment: I did find meta_search, which is like searchlogic and uses scopes to formulate the search results. Still interested in full text stuff though. You can check out meta_search here: http://github.com/ernie/meta_search

Comment: It's like a year later now, but thanks for the suggestions! Ended up going with Thinking Sphinx as it was updated for Rails 3 about a month after posting the original question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx (ver. 2.x) should work with Rails 3 (http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/rails3.html) and there is a Rails 3 branch in the official repository.

I'm just starting to use thinking sphinx in a Rails 3 project, and so far it seems to work fine for basic searching, although I'm having some challenges with acts_as_taggable_on.

Comment: the link is dead now.

Comment: yep, no more need for a separate Rails3 branch anyway. Just see: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/

Comment: Thanks, @Gnomet, Do you know if it is possible to use Sphinx to search a file for example "MS Word" document which is saved in the database in Binary type field?

Answer (score 10):

Check out Sunspot for Solr

http://github.com/outoftime/sunspot

Comment: There is also a screencast on it at [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot).

Comment: Solr is the "industrial-strength" solution. It can handle millions of indexed documents, and has countless configuration points. With all that, though, comes some degree of complexity.

Answer (score 8):

**update** complete change

I would go for [Elasticsearch via Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire)

- super fast
- scalable
- configurable
- super powerful

This is a good resource to start learning: http://exploringelasticsearch.com/book/searching-data/the-query-dsl-and-the-search-api.html

Comment: The link is "dead" now.

Answer (score 1):

Searchlogic was updated to work with Rails3, you can find the new version here: http://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic

Cheers

Comment: Oops sorry. git://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic.git is an old version. You need to install plugin from here git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.git

Comment: But now it isn't stable version. You can use 'or_conditions' branch for creating queries like 'MyModel.title_or_text_like(text)'.\

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/kannanr/acts_as_solr_reloaded

I've modified the code a bit to work with Rails 3... .

Let me know if it works/not...

Answer (score 1):

https://indextank.com/documentation/ruby-client

Answer (score 1):

For a solution without external dependencies, you can try https://github.com/dougal/acts_as_indexed

Answer (score 0):

I have branched and modified acts_as_ferret to pretty much work with rails 3 (ruby 1.8 and 1.9):
https://github.com/brightchimp/acts_as_ferret

3 tests still fail so I suggest running them to see it they will affect your app (more like this, sorting, and pagination (as a result of sorting fail).

I have an outstanding pull request to merge the changes back into the original. In the meantime you can use my branch by specifying the git repo in your gem file:

```
gem 'acts_as_ferret', :git => 'git://github.com/brightchimp/acts_as_ferret.git'
```

The acts_as_ferret gem seemed to fall out of favour a while ago but I still use it. I'm not sure why, but it's worth considering whether it's the best option for any new apps.